# Accessing values in the javascript object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I do not have much practice in js nevertheless I need to use it in my project. I will be grateful for any help.

I need to access values in the object that in Chrome console is shown as on the attached picture. I want to read out values distance and duration. If I try to access it as a simple array distanceDuration[index], I get 'undefined' result. How I can access these values?

[image]

```
function getDistance(origin, destination) {
var distanceDuration = [];
..
distanceDuration[0] = results[j].distance.text;
distanceDuration[1] = results[j].duration.text;

return distanceDuration;
}

var addressElement = document.getElementById('address-autocomplete');


addressElement.addEventListener('change', function() {
    var origin = 'Kraków, Poland';
    var destination = addressElement.value;



  var distanceDuration = getDistance(origin, destination);
    console.log('distanceDuration: ',  typeof distanceDuration); // -> object
  console.log('distanceDuration: ',  distanceDuration);
  //console.log('distanceDuration: ',  distanceDuration[0]); // -> undefined
    ..

}, false);
```

Comment: Post your exact code. We don't know the `index` value.

Comment: Use `distanceDuration[0]` for distance and `distanceDuration[1]` for duration.

Comment: then I get undefined

Comment: @Michal Your array probably is empty at the moment you do your `console.log`. Do you see that blue "i" at its side? Hover over it, it will probably say *"Value below was evaluated just now"*.

Comment: Thank you for that. That was exactly my problem.

Answer (score 0):

I don't exactly understand your problem. Use the index `0` to access the first element in the array (the distance), and `1` to access the second (the duration):

```js
var distanceDuration = ['273 km', '2 hours 55 mins'];
var distance = distanceDuration[0];
var duration = distanceDuration[1];
```

Using destructuring:

```js
var distanceDuration = ['273 km', '2 hours 55 mins'];
var [distance, duration] = distanceDuration;
```

However, using a regular object instead of an array seems to be better choice here:

```js
var distanceDuration = { distance: '273 km', duration: '2 hours 55 mins'];
var distance = distanceDuration.distance;
// using destructuring:
var {duration} = distanceDuration;
```